# expired? can this be resubmitted differently and get a new patent?

Tags: expiration

In reference to the patent: [US4244057](https://www.google.com/patents/US4244057)

Answer (score 1):

US4244057A probably expired about Jan 13, 1998 so the invention described in it is available for anyone to be used. Of course, it cannot be resubmitted for a new patent since an invention needs to be novel in order for a patent to be granted. In other words, the expired patent would be prior art against a new patent application on the same idea. And, importantly you can only patent what you actually invent.

If you can think of a new improvement to the invention in the expired patent, then that improvement could potentially be patented, but it would also have to novel and non-obviousness in light of other patents that might exist.